# How to pass single column values to jquery builder dynamic drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are having requirement to pass column values to jQuery builder for filter dropdown, instead of actual column names.

Like

```
**FieldName**
City
CompanyName
CountryofBirth
```

instead of

```
City | CompanyName | CountryofBirth
```

On the basis of that column values need to build the operator drop down list.

We are able to pass the column name as field to the jquery builder.
but facing problem to pass column values to QueryBuider.

Could you please help me?

Any help will be helpful.

Class - **EmployeeInformation**

```
namespace Castle.DynamicLinqQueryBuilder.Samples.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class EmployeeInformation
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Action method from the controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
            ViewBag.FilterDefinition =
               JsonConvert.SerializeObject(typeof(EmployeeInformation).GetDefaultColumnDefinitionsForType(false), jsonSerializerSettings);
            ViewBag.Model = PersonBuilder.GetPeople();
            return View();
        }
```

**Index** cshtml page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        // Handler for .ready() called.
        var tableData = [];

        var filterDefinition = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.FilterDefinition);
        var customFilters = {
            condition: 'AND',
            rules: []
        };
        debugger;
        var jqueryQueryBuilder = $('#jquery-query-builder');
        var jqueryQueryBuilderDom = jqueryQueryBuilder.queryBuilder({
            plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors', 'filter-description'],
            //allow_groups: 0,
            allow_empty: true,
            filters: filterDefinition,
            rules: customFilters,
            icons: {
                add_group: 'fa fa-plus-square',
                add_rule: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
                remove_group: 'fa fa-minus-square',
                remove_rule: 'fa fa-minus-circle',
                error: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
                sortable: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle'
            }
        });

        var convertArraysToCommaDelimited = function(obj) {
            debugger;
            if (obj != null) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty("value")) {
                    if( Object.prototype.toString.call( obj.value ) === '[object Array]' ) {
                        obj.value = obj.value.join(", ");
                    }
                }
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty("rules") && obj.rules != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < obj.rules.length; i++) {
                        convertArraysToCommaDelimited(obj.rules[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var getRules = function() {
            debugger;
            try {
                var res =  jqueryQueryBuilder.queryBuilder('getRules');
                convertArraysToCommaDelimited(res);
                return res;
            } catch (ex) {
                //console.log(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        var buildTable;
        var filterData = function() {

            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "../Home/Index",
                data: JSON.stringify(getRules()),
                async:false,
                success: function (returnPayload) {

                    alert(JSON.stringify(getRules()));
                    localStorage.setItem('selectedTab', JSON.stringify(getRules()));
                    tableData = returnPayload;
                    buildTable();
                    console && console.log ("request succeeded");
                    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(getRules());
                    alert("This is main json"+jsonString);
                    //AddToDB(jsonString);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console && console.log ("request failed");
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",            
                processData: false,
                async: true
            });
        }

        $('#applyFilter').on('click', function() {
            debugger;
            filterData();
            selectedTab = localStorage.getItem('selectedTab');
            alert("JSON");
            alert(selectedTab);
        });
        buildTable = function() {
            debugger;
            var tbody = $('#data-table tbody'),
                props = ["FirstName", "LastName", "City"];
            tbody.empty();
            $.each(tableData, function(i, reservation) {
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
                    $('<td>').html(reservation[prop]).appendTo(tr);  
                });
                tbody.append(tr);
            });
        };

        filterData();

    });

        function AddToDB()
        {
            alert('Hi')
            var jsonddd="ok";
            var testingJsonString= localStorage.getItem('selectedTab');

            alert(testingJsonString);
            debugger;
            $.ajax({

                url: "../Home/SaveFilterJson",
                type: 'POST',

                dataType: "json",
                data: {jsonvalue:testingJsonString},
                success: function (returnPayload) {

                    alert("For save Method"+JSON.stringify(getRules()));

                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console && console.log ("request failed");
                    alert("Message Error"+thrownError);
                },



            });
        }

</script>
}

<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Dynamic Linq Query Builder Sample</h1>
    <p class="lead">Dynamically filter object collections based on complex queries at runtime.</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Build Filters</h2>
        <div id="jquery-query-builder"></div>
        <button id="applyFilter">Apply Filter</button>

            @*@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveFilterJson","Home",FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <input type="submit" value="Save Filter" id="btnSaveFilter" />
            }*@


            <input type="submit" value="Save Filter" id="btnSaveFilter" onclick="AddToDB();" />

        <label id="lblError" ></label>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>User Data</h2>
        <table id="data-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

[image: JQuery Builder Question One]

---

[image: Query Builder Question Two]

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried like some code snippet would be good.

Comment: Thank you Krishna for your reply. please see the screen shots where i have mention all the steps i have done so far. This code is working for column names but i need to pass column value as column name . for that please see the screen name as "Table column values as column name".

Comment: please post code not screenshots

Comment: Ok sure . please see the code as posted in question.thank you